# Responsive Left Alignment of Title Text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve the text layout below inside a bootstrap card:

[image: Card Layout]

The code beow renders well on large screens but on smaller screens, I'd like the Title to move above the body text. As it is, it just gets crammed into a single long line(non-responsive). How can this be achieved? My code is as below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="card shadow hover-scale-110 mt--100" style="background-color: #F3E500;border-radius: 25px;">
                <div class="card-body p-5">
                    <div style="width: 100%;">
                        <div class="innerDiv" style="width: 15%;">
                            <h2 style="font-weight:bold;">Dear fellow Kenyans</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="innerDiv" style="width: 85%;">
                        <span>Power is one of the most essential utilities in these difficult times of the COVID-19 pandemic.
                            As Mobisol, we are extending a caring hand to help equip the more than 27 million Kenyans staying at home in the dark, with no or limited access to power.
                            Solar energy is easy to acquire, install and inexpensive to use with the sun shining free of charge! We are contributing by making it more affordable and convenient to purchase, transport and install the Mobisol solar power package to benefit these families.
                            Below are our discounted items categorised according to their specifications.<br/>
                        </span><br>
                            <span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">Please join us in spreading the #PowerOfLove.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.innerDiv{
float: left;
width: 100%;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid " style='background-color: #F3E500; border-radius: 50px;'>
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-xs col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 ">
                <h1>
                    <bold>Dear fellow Kenyans</bold>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-xs col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-9">
                <span>Power is one of the most essential utilities in these difficult times of the COVID-19 pandemic.
                As Mobisol, we are extending a caring hand to help equip the more than 27 million Kenyans staying at home in the dark, with no or limited access to power.
                Solar energy is easy to acquire, install and inexpensive to use with the sun shining free of charge! We are contributing by making it more affordable and convenient to purchase, transport and install the Mobisol solar power package to benefit these families.
                Below are our discounted items categorised according to their specifications.<br/>
            </span><br>
                <span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">Please join us in spreading the #PowerOfLove.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

see:https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/4y3fm1Lh/1/
try resizing the window to see effect

Thanks!!!! :-)

Answer (score -1):

```css
<style>
.card-body-content {
  display:flex;
}

.innerDiv.title{
  flex:15;
}

.innerDiv.detail{
  flex:75;
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {
  .card-body-content {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .innerDiv.title{
    flex:1;
  }
  .innerDiv.detail{
    flex:1;
  }
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="card shadow hover-scale-110 mt--100" style="background-color: #F3E500;border-radius: 25px;">
  <div class="card-body p-5">
    <div class="card-body-content" style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="innerDiv title">
        <h2 style="font-weight:bold;">Dear fellow Kenyans</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="innerDiv detail">
        <span>Power is one of the most essential utilities in these difficult times of the COVID-19 pandemic. As Mobisol, we are extending a caring hand to help equip the more than 27 million Kenyans staying at home in the dark, with no or limited access to power. Solar energy is easy to acquire, install and inexpensive to use with the sun shining free of charge! We are contributing by making it more affordable and convenient to purchase, transport and install the Mobisol solar power package to benefit these families. Below are our discounted items categorised according to their specifications.</span>
        <br>
        <strong>Please join us in spreading the #PowerOfLove.</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is just the simplest implementation, hope you can modify it.

Comment: You can replace `@media screen` with something.e.g. `@media width`

Comment: This works, I've tested it, I think you just need to change the `@media`.

Comment: This is notworking  i have tested it in my IDE and in above run code snippet its not